# create a photoset with tumblr api v2

Tags: php, tumblr

I use this php : https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php to create a post with a photo, tags and caption.

```
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client(/*my keys*/);

$data = ['type'     =>  "photo",
             'tags'     =>  "test2, soir",
             'source'   =>  "https://www.google.fr/images/srpr/logo11w.png"];
$client->createPost($blogName, $data);
```

Now I want to upload more than one photo to make a photoset ; so I try

```
'source'    =>  ["https://www.google.fr/images","/* img url */","/* … */"]
```

Photosets is a new feature of Tumblr API, v2 http://engineering.tumblr.com/post/7541361718/introducing-tumblrs-new-api but I don't find any sample of this feature…

Comment: Tumblr API - Posting Photos: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#pphoto-posts

Comment: what does it mean "Array
(URL-encoded binary contents)
Limit: 10 MB" and "One or more image files (submit multiple times to create a slide show)" ? `<?php urlencode('path/to/img.jpg') ?>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it's work!

`$data['data'] = ["1.jpg","2.jpg"];` is ok

`$data['data'] = ["1.jpg","http://path/to/2.jpg"];` is not ok

Comment: mh, I don't understand, you are sending the filesnames..not the  "Array (URL-encoded binary contents) Limit: 10 MB" as stated in the documentation?? is that possible???